# instanceof Carbon fails

Tags: php, laravel, instanceof, php-carbon

In my application I use something like the following

```
if($val instanceof Carbon)
...
```

unfortunately unless I previously use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) in the code (even if just `Carbon::now();`) it will always return false. Why?

Comment: Not sure I understand... How could `$val` be an instance of Carbon at that point if you haven't used the library earlier? (In any case, you probably have a class auto-loader.)

Comment: Can you provide the full code?

Comment: The `Carbon` class's full namespace is `Carbon\Carbon` so your check should be `if ($val instanceof Carbon\Carbon)`. Or if you want to check against only the class name, then have `use Carbon\Carbon;` at the top of the file and then you can use `$val instanceof Carbon`.

Comment: @Bogdan, using `Carbon\Carbon` instead of `Carbon` did the trick, thanks. Add as answer if you want me to accept it.

Comment: @Bogdan Makes sense but user must already have `use Carbon\Carbon;` because he clearly states that he can run `Carbon::now();` successfully.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález you can only have `use Carbon;` and use `Carbon::...` from then on. However I do have `'Carbon' => Carbon\Carbon::class,` defined in `config/app.php`

Comment: @BojanKogoj Bogdan identified the key problem but your Laravel configuration was the missing bit. I've just composed an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Laravel's class auto-loader. You've defined this at `config/app.php`:

```
'Carbon' => Carbon\Carbon::class,
```

... so when you run this for the first time:

```
Carbon::now();
```

... PHP needs a `Carbon` class that is not defined yet so class auto-loading gets triggered and Laravel loads the `Carbon\Carbon` namespace and defines a `Carbon` alias. Thus `$val instanceof Carbon` can return `true` if the variable has the correct type.

However, **`instanceof` itself will not trigger class auto-loading**. [Documentation](http://php.net/instanceof) suggests it did that in the past but it no longer does:

> Before PHP version 5.1.0, instanceof would call __autoload() if the class name did not exist.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/WvBde)

*(I admit I still don't have an explanation of how you can make `$val` be an instance of Carbon if you haven't loaded the class yet.)*